# How to enlarge text clips without distortion in moviepy?

Tags: python, moviepy

I simply use resize to enlarge the text clip. The result is poor.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHJBL.gif)

How to increase the text's font size while keep the text clear?

```
from moviepy.editor import *

screensize = (720,460)
txtClip = TextClip('enlarge', color='white', font="Amiri-Bold",
                    kerning=5, fontsize=50)
text_annimation = txtClip.set_duration(2).resize(lambda t : (1 + 2*t/2)).set_pos('center')

final_clip = CompositeVideoClip([text_annimation],size=screensize).set_fps(24)
```

Answer (score 1):

First generate a very big text clip (`fontsize=200`) then start the resizing from a smaller factor (`resize(lambda t : (0.5 + t/4))`). this way your clip will always be a scaled-down version of the original image, and you won't have any pixelation.

Comment: Good idea! The result looks better in your method. I also tried using gizeh library to create a vector graphic and get the result I want.